# Sending 1-byte number to server

Tags: python

I need to send 1-byte number to server through socket in server-client architecture.

1) How can I convert integer object to 1-byte number (0..255 or -127..127)

2) This code gives me 14, so that means integer object takes 14 bits?

```
import sys
x = 2
print (sys.getsizeof(x))
```

3) I would appreciate some website links connected with data conversion in Python

Comment: An object never has a *name*. There is a variable that refers to that object and the *variable* has name `x`.

Comment: use `struct.pack`.

Comment: Integers in Python can be of arbitrary size. Don't bother with `sys.getsizeof(x)`, you won't get anything useful from that. So before you send an integer over the network you have to ensure it is in an appropriate range. After that you can easily do the convertion: `bytes([x])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a *binary string*. You can construct such a string like:

```
from struct import pack

pack('b', x)
```

This will then construct a binary string that contains here one character (byte), the format is `'b'`. It specifies that we pack one byte (character), in *signed* notation (unsigned would be `'B'`).

We then obtain:

```
>>> pack('b', 2)
b'\x02'
```

Note that the *object* that carries the byte string will be larger:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(pack('b', 2))
34
```

Now we can for instance set up a socket, and send the data to the server, for instance through a TCP/IP connection:

```
import socket
from struct import pack

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8080)) # set IP address and port of the connection

sock.sendall(pack('b', 2))  # send one byte of data through the connection
```

Answer (score 1):

Integers in python don't have a specific size. To send integers, you have to convert them to bytes, using for example `struct.pack`:

```
import struct
x = 2
bytes = struct.pack('b', x)
```